# QGIS 3: Get all Attributes and Objects / Features in View

Tags: qgis-3, attribute-table, fields-attributes

I use attribute tables to store informations about a object/feature on a layer.
I have multiple Layers => multiple attribute tables.

Now I want to have a report about all displayed objects/features (and attributes) with all attribute fields in current view (like layouts and atlas).

In layouts / atlas i can display a legend, but this only get the layersname etc.
I do not mean the label of a feature in (map)view.

How can I do this?

My goal is to get a list of all displayed features/objects with her corresponding attributes.

Regards

Is there a better place to ask QGIS-questions than here?

Comment: So you want to display this in map canvas, not print composer right? I am not aware of such a feature, but it would be nice, indeed. I sometimes misuse copyright notice option together with expressions for this. But it is not very performant.

Comment: No, i want a report.
I do not need a map, a list of all features would be enough.